# How is this add() function working, and why do I get null returned?

Tags: java, spring

When writing code in Spring for an array of objects, I have this code:

```
TaskList parent_list = repo.findOne(listId);

Task t = new Task();
// set fields for t

parent_list.getTasks().add(t);
repo.save(parent_list);
```

Here, `repo` is a repository of `TaskList`s, and is an extension of `JpaRepository` in Spring Data JPA.
`parent_list` contains some data about itself(name, owner) and a `List<Task>`.

My question is, before the call to `save()`, how is the add() function working? Why don't I need to return a value(i.e. need to do `parentList.setTasks(parent_list.getTasks().add(t));`)?

I am getting a null object as a result of the `repo.save()`.

I only have a repository for the `TaskList` object, not the `Task`. I was under the impression that there is no need for an extra repo; all you need is a relationship with the table from the first table and the entries are saved automatically.

Comment: I'm thinking along these lines: If you need to add 1 to a variable `c`, you do `c = c + 1`, not just `c + 1`. So won't I need to return something here as well?

Comment: This is basic java. You have a Collection. You call add. The object is added to the collection. Why would you need to return something?!

Comment: @BillyFrost I just got confused a bit. I thought we'd need something like `parentList.setTasks(parent_list.getTasks().add(t));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is one-to-many relationship between `TaskList` and `Task`. `TaskList` returns its tasks with `getTasks()` method which returns `List<Task>`. Via the method `add()` you add new element into the list. Here comes the magic - the `List` is provided by hibernate and it has special handling when new item is added or removed from the list. Once you persist those operations, it will run SQL queries/updates/deletes to propagate your changes into database.

Comment: I've added to the question; what you said in your last sentence isn't happening.

Comment: For future readers, adding `cascade` attribute to the parent `TaskList` table solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the fact that `add()` is a function makes all the difference.

The `add()` function will have the assignment somewhere in it that appends the `Task` passed to it to the `List<Task>`.